# JavaScript ¿Cómo mostrar fecha actual. ejemplo: hoy es 21 de octubre de 2020?

Tags: javascript, html, date, math

el numero del día, el nro. del mes y el año lo tengo que tomar de la PC.
para obtener el nombre del mes, debo crear una función, que pasándole el nro. de mes, devuelva el nombre del mismo.

Hasta ahora hice esto pero no puedo obtener que muestre el nombre del mes en vez del numero.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
       <title>Dia de la semana </title>
       
      </head>
      <body>
            <script>

             var fecha = new Date();
             document.write("\nHoy es: "+fecha.getDate()+"\ndel "+(fecha.getMonth()+1)+"\ndel "+fecha.getFullYear());
             
             document.write('<br>');
             document.write('<br>');
             
             document.write("\nSon las: "+fecha.getHours()+"\n: "+fecha.getMinutes()+"\n: "+fecha.getSeconds());
            

             </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function zero(n) {
    return (n>9 ? '' : '0') + n;
}
    let date  = new Date();
      let strDate = zero(date.getDate())  + "-" + zero((date.getMonth()+1)) + "-" + date.getFullYear() ;
    console.log(strDate);
      let months = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo","Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre","Diciembre"];

    let month = months[date.getMonth()]; 
    console.log(month);
```

Te dejo un codigo que te sirve para lo que estas buscando, tambien si deseas saber el nombre del dia, colocas let days = ["Lunes", "Martes", etc...] y luego let day = days[date.getDay()];
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tendrías que hacer en crear un array en con los meses del año, días de la semana y crear una variable para el día actual y recorrerlo el array de acuerdo al dia,mes y año.

```js
          var meses = new Array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
          var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Mi&eacute;rcoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "S&aacute;bado");
          var f = new Date();
          document.write(diasSemana[f.getDay()] + " " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " del " + f.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Discúlpame lo edite la respuesta espero sea mas entendible saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar los métodos [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/toLocaleDateString) y [toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/toLocaleTimeString) que tienen buen soporte en navegadores.

```js
// toLocaleDateString
var laFecha = new Date().toLocaleDateString(
  'es-ar', {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  }
);

// toLocaleTimeString
var laHora = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(
  'es-ar', {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  }
);

document.getElementById('hoyes').innerHTML = laFecha;
document.getElementById('sonlas').innerHTML = laHora;


// original
var fecha = new Date();
document.write("\nHoy es: " + fecha.getDate() + "\ndel " + (fecha.getMonth() + 1) + "\ndel " + fecha.getFullYear());

document.write('<br>');
document.write('<br>');

document.write("\nSon las: " + fecha.getHours() + "\n: " + fecha.getMinutes() + "\n: " + fecha.getSeconds());
```

```css
span {
  background: #fe0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dia de la semana </title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hoy es: <span id=hoyes></span></p>
  <p>Son las: <span id=sonlas></span></p>
  <hr/>
</body>

</html>
```